# Обычное меню: теория и практика

Tags: html, javascript

Всем доброго времени суток.

Давно хотел сделать такую элементарщину... при наведении на определенный текст, ссылку, ячейку в таблице хочу, чтобы снизу появлялась белая область (желательно таблица), с указанными мной ссылками. Ссылки должны быть равны определенным переменным ($u01, $u02, $u03...). Конечно, "гуголь рулит", но такую менюху делаю первый раз, и подводных камней не знаю. Поэтому вопроса два.

Первый: охота узнать, на чем максимально стандартном, кросс-браузерном, древнем, внутри страницы, без библиотечном можно написать эту менюшку?

Второй: как такое написать? Кто может написать "скромный" пример?

Comment: ну не я один жру мозг=)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<style>
.rollover{position:relative}
.rollover .tip{position:absolute;top:-20px;left:50%;width:150px;margin-left:-75px;background:#0cf;display:none}
.rollover:hover .tip{display:block}
</style>
<span class="rollover"><div class="tip">I'm popup</div>roll me over to see an interesting effect</span>
```

Есть вот такой вариант. Но его надо немного допилить в плане верстки. Сумеете сами? =)

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял, то Вам нужен попап, вот [пример](http://zort.ru/). Оно?

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1251">
</head>

<body>

<table id="menu1" onMouseOver="document.all.tb1.style.display=''" onClick="menuclick()" onMouseOut="document.all.tb1.style.display='none'" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="10" rules="none" border="1">

<tbody>
<tr><td id="menuzag1" onMouseOver="=onmousemenu()" onMouseOut="outmousemenu()">p_one</td></tr>
</tbody>

<tbody id="tb1" style="display:none">
<tr><td id="n001" onMouseOver="onelement()" onMouseOut="outelement()">one</td></tr>
</tbody>

</table>

<script type="text/javascript">

// in
function oneelement(){
xid=event.srcElement.id
document.all[xid].style.color='#ffffff'
document.all[xid].style.background='#ffffff'
}

// en
function outelement(){
xid=event.srcElement.id
document.all[xid].style.color='#000000'
document.all[xid].style.background='#ffffff'
}

// in h
function onmousemenu(){
xid=event.srcElement.id
document.all[xid].style.background='#ffffff'
}

// en h
function outmousemenu(){
xid=event.srcElement.id
document.all[xid].style.background='#ffffff'
}

// fe
function menuclick(){
alert("element: " +event.srcElement.id)
if(event.srcElement.id=="n001"){ window.open("http://ya.ru")  }
}

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

из минусов - javascript. без этого никак? (jQuery... и прочее тож не охота использовать).

вот пример. косяки: при наведении на меню, кнопку и обратно - исчезает линия разделитель. при нажатии в место перехода идет окно и потом переход, при чем не в этом же окне а в другом.

сложность вот в чем: перед скриптом у меня есть пару переменных, их мне охота запихать в место "http://ya.ru", как такое сделать?

Comment: без js никак, развичто flash, но это бессмыслено...